# How this query can be answered ? Select SUM(1) FROM table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench, sql-query-store

`select * from "Test"."EMP"`

```
id
1
2
3
4
5
```

```
Select SUM(1) FROM "Test"."EMP";
Select SUM(2) FROM "Test"."EMP";
Select SUM(3) FROM "Test"."EMP";
```

why the output of these queries is?

```
5
10
15
```

And
I don't understand why they write table name like this "Test"."EMP"

Comment: You are just adding the numbers 1, 2, and 3, not the IDs from the table. The first query computes as 1 x 5 = 5. The second one computes 2 x 5 = 10. The third one is 3 x 5 = 15.

Answer (score 0):

your table has 5 records. the statement `select 1 from test.emp` returns 5 records with values as 1 for all 5 records.

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 1 |

This is because db engine simply returns 1 for each existing record without reading the contents of the cell. and same happens for `select <any static value> from test.emp`

same happens for 2 and 3

| id |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 2 |

hence there are 5 records returned with the static values and sum of those values will be the `product` of `static number` passed in the select statement and `total records` in the table

> *additional fact: It is always recommended to perform `count(1)` than `count(*)` as it consumes less resource and hence less load on the server*

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's  `"Test"."EMP"` with double quotes.. it's probably `` `Test`.`EMP` `` with backticks instead. The definition means its `database_name.table_name`. This is the recommended format to get the correct `table_name` from `database_name`; in this case, you're specifically making the syntax to query from `` `Test`.`EMP` ``. Read more about [identifier qualifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html).

As for `SUM(x)`, the `x` get's repeated according to the rows present in the table. So `SUM(1)` on 5 rows is `1+1+1+1+1`, `SUM(2)` on 5 rows is `2+2+2+2+2`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This is very typical `SQL` interview question which is generally asked.
People got confuse with `sum` of 1,2,3. Actually it is sum of all rows considering 1 for each row similarly for 2 not the `sum` of first row which ID value is 1.

So `sum` of 1 would be

> `(1+1+1+1+1) =5`

> `(2+2+2+2+2) =10`

> `(3+3+3+3+3) =15`